# Symfony2 get methods on collection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I wanna use a get-method on a collection - but it is not working.

```
$user = $this->getUser(); // Single User object -> all fine!
$abc = $user->getABC(); // getABC is a collection of multiple objects -> still fine!
$random = $abc->getRandom(); // method getRandom not working on collection -> ERROR Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection::getRandom()
```

I tried it with a foreach loop, but i didnt manage to make it work.

Is there any way, to tell symfony2 to use the getRandom method on every object of this collection?

In the end, I wanna have a list of all entries, which are made by my user.
If you need more information -> comment! =)

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($abc as $rand) {
    $random = $rand->getRandom();
}
```

Just a simple loop over all elements. This is possible because the `ArrayCollection` implements the `IteratorAggregate` interface. See the [PHP Docs](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.iteratoraggregate.php)

Comment: Omg haha, i was online with the wrong user -> and rights-management ruined it. Thanks tho! :O

Answer (score 0):

Why not use:

```
$random = $abc->get(rand(0, $abc->count() - 1));
```

Reference:
http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.3/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html

Comment: Umm, what are you trying there?^^ Sorry

Comment: If your trying to get a random number from 0 to abc - $random was just a random name, i gave my variable, cause im not allowed to write my real variables in here :O^^ its more about getting the attribute "random" for example, with getRandom()

Comment: Ow, I missed the rand function, I fix it

Comment: Ok I understand your question, you want to call a method on every object of a collection. So the foreach loop should work...

Comment: Probably, but i didnt manage to make it work with a foreach yet.